# impedance matching single vs series capacitor

Tags: rf, antenna, impedance, impedance-matching

Im looking at a impedance matching circuit on a schematic that shows a .75pF capacitor pulled to ground.

With my current board design I have a 1pF and a 3.3pF on the board already so I am thinking of using these two in series to create .75pF.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDPuTe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am no RF guru so I am curious if this has bad implications at 2.4GHz.

Aside from making sure I am using something that has similar:

- type
- ESR
- voltage-rating
- tolerance
- temperature coefficient

To Clarify: In the original schematic it shows the single .75pF. I am curious if its OK to switch this out for the two series caps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you see series capacitors at such low values is that the parasitic capacitance beomes significant.  With the multiple caps in series, much of the parasitic capacitance is also in series, so is divided by the number of caps.  The deliberate capacitance you get is also divided by the number of caps, but you can chose to make that higher to compensate.

This trick works best when the individual capacitances are roughly equal.  1 and 3.3 pF in series does yield about 770 fF, but the result would be more reliable with two 1.5 pF caps in series.

Another reason two caps like this are sometimes used in RF circuits is for trimming.  The designer knows he wants a bit less than 1 pF, so puts a 1 pF cap in series with another part.  The resulting series value is then a reduced function of the second cap, giving you more resolution to hit the desired value from commonly available parts.  Quite possibly, the second value was found by experimentation for that particular board.  It may even be determined at production time from some calibration procedure.

Comment: Olin - just to clarify...In the original schematic it shows the single .75pF. I am curious if its OK to switch this out for the two series caps.

Comment: @Tman: Yes, you can use the two caps in series.  However, since parasitic capacitance will be significant at these values, you may have to experiment a little to get the right value.